# Why does function declaration has a name property whereas variable does not in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have realized that

```js
function hello(){}
document.write(typeof hello); // outputs function
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(hello.name); // outputs name
```

whereas

```js
var hello = function(){}
document.write(typeof hello); // outputs function
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(hello.name); // doesn't output anything
```

Can you explain why? It seems that functions are not the same.

Comment: It does have a property `name`, but since you didn't name the function, it's an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example, the variable `hello` points to an *anonymous function expression*.

You can write *named function expressions* too

```
var foo = function bar() {};
console.log(foo.name); // "bar"
```

---

Using a named function expression is great for recursing in *strict mode*, but **in old versions of IE** you'll find the identifier leaks into the namespace.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, I will mark your answer as the answer but SO doesn't allow me to do that in 15 min. So I will have to wait until that time expires.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the second form, declare it this way:

```
 var hello = function hello() {}
```

And you'll be able to get to the name property.  It may seem redundant, but this is a pretty good habit, and we enforce it where we work.  It makes stack traces easier to follow, and any minifier worth its salt will remove the actual name unless it's referred to.  The names don't have to match.

Comment: It seems like a really good information you provided up there! Thanks a lot mate!